# MySQL create table with unique year-month-day key in datetime field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `cases` (
  `pid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `code` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL)
```

Example content:

```
 pid |                date | code
----------------------------------
   1 | 2021-02-07 08:00:00 |  'a'
   2 | 2021-02-07 12:00:00 |  'b'
   1 | 2021-02-08 12:00:00 |  'a'
```

I want a unique key on this table, so that is not possible to store the same `code` for the same `pid` more than once on the **same day**.

Something like `UNIQUE KEY pid_date_code (pid, date_format(date, '%y%m%d'), code)`

Speed is not important in my case, the table will contain less than 10.000 rows.

Is this even possible? Everything I tried so far was not successful.

Comment: Add generated column which extracts date only from the datetime. Use it in unique index.

Comment: @Akina You took the words out of my mouth.  Please add this as an answer +1.

Comment: Depending on your server version, you may be able to create a [functional index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `cases` (
  `pid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `code` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  dateonly DATE AS (DATE(`date`)),
  UNIQUE (pid, code, dateonly));
```

`dateonly` column may be virtual (if server version allows).

Comment: Thank you! I used this command to edit my table: `ALTER TABLE cases ADD dateonly DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE(date)) STORED`

Comment: @larwain And one more statement for unique constraint creation needed. And I do not see the reason to make this column stored (but you may if it will be used intensively) - its value will be extracted from the index when needed.